# Asynchronous call of a SQL Server stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, asynchronous

Is it possible to **call a SQL Server stored procedure asynchronously** via C#?

I have a stored procedure which writes a backup of a specific database (this can take a long time to complete) and I want to show the progress of the backup process in a windows forms (for this I use http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/articles/tsql_backup_restore_progress.aspx). Or should I use the Backgroundworker control and run the SP in a backgroundjob (own thread) ?

Answer (score 12):

In your `SqlCommand` you can run commands asynchronously using `BeginExecuteNonQuery` and `EndExecuteNonQuery`.  The latter will block until its done.  However this won't report the progress from the server about how the backup is going - I'd use a marquee progress bar for it.

To avoid the `EndExecuteNonQuery` from blocking your UI (depending on how you handle it), you will need a background thread.  If you use this then you may as well not use `BeginXXX` `EndXXX` methods and do it synchronously on a background thread - the `BackgroundWorker` is best for this.

To avoid using a background thread in the UI, instead of blocking on `EndXXX` you will need to register a callback and handle the resulting event (calling `EndXXX` in this event handler, but it will return immediately).

**Update:** as per a comment, for asynchronous calls into the SQL command/connection stuff, you need to specify as much in the connection string:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

```
Server=myServerAddress; Database=myDataBase; Integrated Security=True; Asynchronous Processing=True;
```

Or in code using the connection string builder:

```
builder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
```

Comment: And you need to set builder.AsynchronousProcessing = true; in the connection string builder.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it in a separate thread anyway, so I would probably go for the BackgroundWorker approach.