# Thread was being aborted in long SP executing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, sql-server-2005, timeout

I've created a asp.net page which execute a very long sp (about 1 hour of sp execution time in SSMS).

there is an Admin.aspx which activate this SP.

in web.config I've added:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="111264" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="10000000" />
```

also in the connection properties Ive added :

```
_cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; // unlimited
```

the function is using jquery ajax (to ashx) to activate the sp (it is working and fine)

the jquery calls an ashx file which activate the sp .

However I didn't want the the UI will be blocked till the end of the operation so i created a thread in the ashx file :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
{
    string xmlFileNameParam = ...
    string bakFileName = ...

    ParameterizedThreadStart ThreadWithParam = dbFuncForThread;

    Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadWithParam);
    thread.IsBackground = false;

    dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
    d.XmlFileNameParam = xmlFileNameParam;
    d.BakFileName = bakFileName;
    thread.Start(d);
}

public void dbFuncForThread(dynamic d)
{
    // activate the long sp
}
```

However after a while , i see this error in the EventLog (and the operation stopped):**

> There is a problem line 259Thread was being aborted.
>      at System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)*

Why?

I gave the thread all the environment it needed (connection timeout, execution timeout)

P.S.
If I don't use a thread and put a normal code like this (UI Is blocked though):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)        
{
    string xmlFileNameParam = ...
    string bakFileName = ...

    dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
    d.XmlFileNameParam = xmlFileNameParam;
    d.BakFileName = bakFileName;

    dbFuncForthread(d);   
}

public void dbFuncForThread(dynamic d  )
{
    //  activate the long sp...
}
```

So the code is fine and everything is fine. How and why is that and how do I solve it?

Comment: Perhaps time to optimize the stored procedure?

Comment: @oded the sp is pretty simple , it loads a bak file , and scramble the data and the saves a new bak of it.... its just hash data... pretty simple sp.

Comment: @Royi: Why do you use dynamic objects?

Comment: @Royi: Why then is it running so long?!

Comment: @abatishchev , is you use ParameterizedThreadStart   - and you pass a pram - so it has to be a type of object which translated later to object[] ,  I wanted to use dynamics, it does matter

Comment: @abatishchev please see my response to Oded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may reconsider your design, better use windows service to do this for you. From webservice pass data to windows service which thn execute sp. The obvious problem for this scenario in web environment couldbe IISReset or appdomain recycle will abort all threads.

Comment: so why if i remove the thread- its working? its still running under the iis...?

Comment: when you dont do it asynchronously, your app is active and not eligible for apppool recycle, but if you fire and forget thread, these new thread will be alive depending on IIS X pool recycling algorithm. You may try increasing app pool idle timeout ancd see if it helps.

Comment: you were right. I disabled the recycle when idle - and all is fine (no need to beginXXX methods) . But Can you please clarify this : **When its simple sync operation - so it can wait 1 year to complete , but when i do it with thread - so it does consider the idle timeout to recycle.. why is that ? does my  background thread is less important ??**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the thread doesn't like having to wait so long for the SP to complete, it isn't a SQL call time-out. Rather than explicitly starting a new thread to call the SP, can you just call it asynchronously: [Asynchronous call of a SQL Server stored procedure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288272/asynchronous-call-of-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp) ?

Comment: If I use your tip , aka beginXXX - so the asp.net wont wait for it ? also ,  why it seems that it **does** wait for my thread **EVEN** if i tell him thats its a new thread...?

Comment: You can call endXX if you need to wait.  Not entirely sure what is going on with your code above.  I think in general executing something that takes 1 hour in a page life cycle is a bad idea.  I would re factor the application so that you initiate the process in one request and allow that request to complete immediately.  If you need to perform further work on completion of the SP come up with another solution for this.