# run database query and not wait for result

Tags: c#, database, loops, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I need to call a stored proc that does quite a bit of work.

I want to be able to "fire and forget" e.g not wait for the response of the stored proc before moving onto the next record as that slows things down and I need to be moving quickly.

What is the best method of calling a stored proc in C# and NOT waiting for the result, returning a success status, and then moving onto the next record.

I'd like to be able to just quickly loop through my object list of selections and call some method that does the DB call without waiting for the response before moving to the next item in the loop.

It's using C# 4.5.

I was thinking about using something like

```
Parallel.ForEach(sqlRecordset.AsEnumerable(), recordsetRow =>
{
  // get data for selection
  // call DB to save without waiting for response / success/failure status
}
```

But I don't know if this is the best approach or not.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: depends, will this create a 1000 DB connections?  You need to be able to set some governing controls to prevent a DB connection drain.

Comment: Async calls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288272/asynchronous-call-of-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp

Comment: Concurrent queue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Answer (score 5):

`Parallel.ForEach` is **parallel but synchronous** - it will wait for all its iterations to finish.

You may use [TPL (Task Parallel Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve what you want:

```
foreach (var recordsetRow_doNotUse in sqlRecordset.AsEnumerable())
{
    var recordsetRow = recordsetRow_doNotUse;
    Task.Run(() => { 
        Console.WriteLine(recordsetRow);
        /* or do whatever you want with it here */ 
    });
}
```

`Task.Run` returns a task so if you need to do something when all of them are done you can put all of them in an array and then use `Task.WhenAll` to obtain a Task which will be complete when all iterations are complete, without blocking any threads.

P.S. I don't know what you mean by C# 4.5, probably .NET 4.5 which is C# 5. My sample code above won't work with earlier versions of C#.

Comment: Hi I have created a method using command.BeginExecuteNonQuery but now my log file is full of errors = The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets. My Data Class opens one connection and holds it so that new ones are not spawned for every request - is this the problem? I am using .NET 4.0 actually (just checked) and MS SQL 2005 for this DB. Its an old work DB they are letting me test on. Any ideas to get round or solve this error?

Comment: I edited my code so it will work with C# 4. From the error you get it looks like you can't use your connection for parallel requests. It might be ok to create a new connection each your Data Class object is created, just try it and see if it gets a lot slower.

Comment: Is it possible to use it with ASP.NET? I mean does it stay running even after the ASP.NET request is finished? Isn't it possible that after the request is done, the database connection is closed and stored procedure is killed or rolled back?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy - yes, but you're better off using [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Bond Thank you. Could you also briefly describe, why `Task` solution is not good, please? (since it's very simple and it works)

Comment: If you see the link about QueueBackgroundWorkItem above you'll find the explanation:
*Differs from a normal ThreadPool work item in that ASP.NET can keep track of how many work items registered through this API are currently running, and the ASP.NET runtime will try to delay AppDomain shutdown until these work items have finished executing.*

Answer (score 3):

The easier approach is using ADO.NET:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("storeProcName", sqlConnection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: In his case how does it solve the problem? I am curious to understand.

Comment: This invokes the SP but id doesn't wait for the result.

Comment: cool,so it just fires the command to the DB and doesn't wait for the response or return recordset? What happens if the stored proc DOES return a recordset. Will it just get ignored? Or is there a way to parse it still? Not that I want to do anything with the returned recordset I just want to know for "knowledges" sake. Thanks

Comment: If you want the results you can use the return value to invoke the cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery (or any other method with begin/end signature).

Comment: @StefanoAltieri why does it doesnt seem to execute the command when i used this?

Comment: It is not synchronous. It runs on another thread, can be tricky to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like to iterate through each records, get some values and store it in the database and not wait for any record set, you could do something like below; Assuming you are using windows application and know threading;

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable.Rows) //you can use any enumerable object here
{
    string s = row.Fields("name").ToString();
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SaveName));
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.start(s);
}

public void SaveName(object s)
{
    //your code to save the value in 's'
}
```

This way, you will not have to wait for the database to respond and every values will be saved. The threads will be destroyed as soon as it finish saving and processing your records..

Hope this helps.

Happy coding..!!

Comment: Would this spawn lots of connections to the DB like the person above said it could as this is what I am worried about. As I am using a DB at work to test on which has important sites I don't want to consume all available connections by my own code. Is there a way in SQL 2005+ within a stored proc to fire off a ANOTHER stored proc without waiting for the results (without resorting to writing C# CLR procs)? so I could call my proc in the usual loop fashion, not consume lots of connections, and then let the proc fire and forget?

Comment: You could declare a global connection object on the class level and use it for calling multiple instances of stored procedure. This would create only one connection to database with multiple request to execute the stored procedure. Hope this helps. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.